# Java UDP - server accepting packets on multiple ports

Tags: java, tcp, udp, port

I have quite a complex question here, I hope understanding my code won't be such a problem.

I'm writing a program based on UDP and TCP communication in Java. 
Server is listening on several UDP ports (1. number and quantity of ports is given by a user in program parameters; 2. A Thread is created for each port) for a packets from Clients (there can be more than one trying to send a packet at a time to Server). Each packet contains Clients id, the message and UDP port number of the Client who send this packet. Server receives the packet, puts the message in a HashMap (Client id is the key, sent messages are stored in a List of Strings). On each packet received, Servers checks the List of Strings whether the messages sent from specified Client are matching a password. If the messages are in correct order, Server sends a generated port number for TCP communication with the Client who has sent the correct password, opens ServerSockets, they perform a simple communication and the Client closes.

Now, a Client should be able to send his messages to various ports. For example, Server is listening on ports 2000 and 3000. A Client should be able to send 2 messages to port 2000 and another two messages on port 3000. However, the Server seems to be be receiving messages only on the first opened port.

If a Client sends all his messages on one port, it all works fine.

Here is the Server class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Server {

    static int portsOpenedQuantity;
    static HashMap<String, List<String>> packetsReceived = new HashMap<>();
    static List<Integer> portsTCP = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        portsOpenedQuantity = args.length;

        List<String> listOfPorts = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < portsOpenedQuantity; ++i)
            if(!listOfPorts.contains(args[i]) && (Integer.parseInt(args[i]) > 1024))
                listOfPorts.add(args[i]);       

        for(int i = 0; i < listOfPorts.size(); ++i) {
            final int j = i;
            System.out.println("SERVER listening on port: " + listOfPorts.get(j));

            Thread listeningPort = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    synchronized (packetsReceived){
                        try {
                            byte[] packetReceived = new byte[256];
                            DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(Integer.parseInt(listOfPorts.get(j)));
                            DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(packetReceived, 256);
                            while(true){
                                ds.receive(dp);
                                List<String> sequence = new ArrayList<>();
                                System.out.println("SERVER received a packet");
                                String msgReceived = new String(dp.getData(), 0, dp.getLength());
                                String[] separatedMsg = msgReceived.split(" ");
                                int portUDPNumber = Integer.parseInt(separatedMsg[2]);
                                System.out.println("Id: " + separatedMsg[0]);
                                System.out.println("Value: " + separatedMsg[1]);
                                System.out.println("Port UDP: " + separatedMsg[2]);
                                if(packetsReceived.containsKey(separatedMsg[0])) {
                                    sequence = packetsReceived.get(separatedMsg[0]);
                                    packetsReceived.remove(separatedMsg[0]);
                                    System.out.println(separatedMsg[1]);
                                    sequence.add(separatedMsg[1]);
                                    System.out.println(sequence);
                                    packetsReceived.put(separatedMsg[0], sequence);
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println(sequence);
                                    sequence.add(separatedMsg[1]);
                                    packetsReceived.put(separatedMsg[0], sequence);
                                }

                                String sequenceResult = "";
                                for(int k = 0; k < sequence.size(); ++k) {
                                    sequenceResult += sequence.get(k);
                                }
                                System.out.println(sequenceResult);

                                if(sequenceResult.equals("!@#$")){
                                    System.out.println("Connecting via TCP...");
                                    int portNumber = (int)((Math.random()*100)+5000);
                                    boolean portAvailable = true;
                                    ServerSocket ss = null;
                                    System.out.println("TCP port number: " + portNumber);
                                    while(portAvailable) {
                                        try{
                                            ss = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
                                            portsTCP.add(portNumber);
                                            portAvailable = false;
                                        } catch(Exception e) {
                                            portAvailable = true;
                                            portNumber++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    System.out.println("socket number aquired");
                                    String portNr = portNumber+"";
                                    byte[] portNrToSend = portNr.getBytes();
                                    dp = new DatagramPacket(portNrToSend, portNrToSend.length, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), portUDPNumber);
                                    System.out.println("Datagram created");
                                    ds.send(dp);
                                    System.out.println("Datagram sent");
                                    Socket s = ss.accept();
                                    System.out.println("Port number sent to: " + portUDPNumber);
                                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
                                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));          
                                    String msgFromClient = in.readLine();
                                    System.out.println("Message from client: " + msgFromClient);
                                    out.println("I received your message");
                                    in.close();
                                    out.close();
                                    s.close();
                                    ss.close();
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            listeningPort.start();
        }
    }

}
```

And the Client class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Client {

    InetAddress ip;
    String idClient;
    List<Integer> portsUDP = new ArrayList<>();
    String sequence;

    public Client(String[] args) {
        try {
            ip = InetAddress.getByName(args[0]);
            idClient = args[1];
            for(int i = 2; i < args.length; ++i)
                portsUDP.add(Integer.parseInt(args[i]));
            this.sequence = "!@#$"; 

            DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket();
            DatagramPacket dp = null;
            for(int i = 0; i < portsUDP.size(); ++i) {
                byte[] toSend = new byte[256];
                String msgToSend = idClient + " " + sequence.charAt(i) + " " + ds.getLocalPort();
                System.out.println("CLIENT named as: " + idClient + " sends a message: " + sequence.charAt(i) + " " + ds.getLocalPort());
                toSend = msgToSend.getBytes();
                dp = new DatagramPacket(toSend, toSend.length, ip, portsUDP.get(i));
                ds.send(dp);
                System.out.println("CLIENT: " + idClient + " sent a packet");
                toSend = new byte[256];
                msgToSend = "";
            }

            String received;
            byte[] tabReceived = new byte[256];
            dp = new DatagramPacket(tabReceived, tabReceived.length);
            System.out.println("Datagram created");
            ds.receive(dp);
            System.out.println("Datagram received");
            received = new String(dp.getData(), 0, dp.getLength());
            System.out.println("Received TCP port number: " + received);
            int portTCP = Integer.parseInt(received);

            int portNumber = (int)((Math.random()*100)+5000);
            boolean portAvailable = true;
            ServerSocket ss = null;
            while(portAvailable) {
                try{
                    ss = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
                    portAvailable = false;
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    portAvailable = true;
                    portNumber++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("ServerSocket created");
            Socket s = new Socket(ip, portTCP);
            System.out.println("Socket created");
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            out.println("Succes of communication");
            String msgFromServer = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message from SERVER: " + msgFromServer);
            in.close();
            out.close();
            s.close();
            ss.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Client(args);
    }

}
```

I think what is creating problems here is the synchronization on the HashMap, but when I run it without synchronization, the packets come in a completely random sequence, are not stored in the HashMap properly - it's just much worse.

I'd be grateful for any suggestions and comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Runnable` loops forever after obtaining a lock on a shared object called `packetsReceived`, so only one of your Threads will actually be able to accomplish anything; the other thread will wait for the lock forever.

You should be able to verify this with a simple thread dump while your sample program is running.

The solution (to the synchronization problem) is to only obtain that lock when you want to actually modify the `HashMap`. So, remove the `synchronized(packetsReceived)` from outside the loop and put it around the code that actually performs the `containsKey`/`remove`/`put` calls on the `HashMap`.

Comment: When I did that, all messages are incoming, but they are not in order. I tried to make the Client sleep every time he sends a message, so that the Server would be able to receive the packets in correct order, but that generated more problems (when I use TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(), Server somehow cuts 2 first messages incoming from the Client).

Comment: How are you determining the "order" of the received messages?